# Can't I run an app after installing .NET Framework 4?

Tags: frameworks

Please use simple English, my language skills are not as good as yours! :)

I installed .NET Framework 4 for one app but when I run the setup for that app, I see this error:

> Installer information
>
> Microsoft .NET framework 3.5 SP1 or greater
>   needs to be installed!

I installed .NET Framework 4 and 3 SP1 but I can't insatll my app! The app programer said that just .NET Framwork 4 should be installed!

Comment: I would suggest to uninstall .NET and reinstall. Something did work properly.

Answer (score 0):

the Installer for .NET 4 does not include the installer for .NET 3.5 you need to install the .NET 3.5 framework as well as the .NET 4 framework.

Here's the link for the standalone installer:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe